# Check that Python function does not modify argument?

Tags: python

You know how in Python, if `v` is a list or a dictionary, it's quite common to write functions that modify `v` in place (instead of just returning the new value). I'm wondering if it is possible to write a checker that identifies such functions.

For simplicity, say you have a function `f`, which only takes one argument - `a` and returns in finite time (the return value is actually irrelevant). Assume also that for any input value `v`, `f(v)` always does the same thing (i.e. the logic inside of `f` does not depend on any context or environment values - it's a pure computation on `a`).

Is it possible to write a function `m`, such that `m(f, v)` returns `True` if and only if `f(v)` actually changes the original value of `v`?

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: I think, in generic case, that boils down to e.g. halting problem which is proved to be not solvable algorithmically.

Comment: Do a copy.deepcopy of object before you pass it in and then compare the copy with what you see afterwards

Comment: @jbasko if that function modifies the input only on certain conditions, that won't prove anything.

Comment: without thinking too much: if `v` is a list, you could see what happens to `f(v=tuple(...))` (the same for a `dict` usind a `frozendict`)...

Comment: @bereal i didn't see him ask for a proof or mention that this is a theoretical question. Sounded like a practical beginner problem.

Comment: IMHO, functions that mutate any of their arguments ought to document that behaviour, so you shouldn't _need_ to write such a testing function...

Comment: @jbasko you're right it's a practical question, but not exactly a beginner one. I actually had a working `deepcopy` solution before I even posted the question, but I wasn't sure that's the best way of going about this. I wanted to see the resulting discussion - which has been quite delightful so far - especially @jwodder 's "proof".

Answer (score 4):

No; this is equivalent to the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  If such an `m` did exist, then I could just write:

```
def f(a):
    if m(f, a):
        return a
    else:
        # Modify `a` somehow
        return a
```

and we get a contradiction.

Comment: This looks very convincing, except in my practical use case, it is entirely reasonable to also assume that `f` would never call `m`. Does this change things?

Comment: @JordanDimov: Just copy the source code of `m` into `f` instead (They're both Python functions, so you can do it).  Then `f` doesn't technically call `m`, but it still does the same thing.

Comment: Sure, but that's not my point. What you've done is you have proven that there is a certain function `f`, for which `m(f)` can not be computed. But in practice, I'm OK with that, as long as for most practical functions, `m` still works. For example, the simple `deepcopy` solutions suggested by @jbasko and Rafael actually seem good enough for me. Moreover, your example function can not even run with this particular implementation of `m`, due to infinite recursion (`m` calls `f`, which calls `m`, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check that behavior you can write a simple blackbox test using `deepcopy` of the original value something like:

```
def m(f, a):
    original = copy.deepcopy(a)
    f(a)
    return original != a

def f(a):
    a.append('a')

def k(a):
    b = a

z = ['b']
m(f, z) # True
z = ['b']
m(k, z) # False
```

Of course, if the argument is a `list` of `dict` you have to deepcopy and compare the inner objects, but it's the same logic

Answer (score 0):

a **very rudimentary** first shot at this that works for iterables only (and no: i do not claim this solves the halting problem or works in the general case...):

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

def changes(lst):
    lst.append(0)

def no_changes(lst):
    return

def tries_to_change(f, v):
    if isinstance(v, Sequence):
        v_immutable = tuple(v)
        try:
            f(v_immutable)
            return False
        except AttributeError:
            return True

print(tries_to_change(f=changes, v=[1, 2, 3]))  # True
print(tries_to_change(f=no_changes, v=[1, 2, 3]))  # False
```

the idea is to cast the input to an immutable version of the same datastructure and see what happens. very crude!

and as mentioned by *jbasko* in the comments: this only prevents setting and deleting of elements; modifications of the elements themselves (e.g. if the argument is a list of a list; you could still change the 'inner' list) will go undetected.

minor update thanks to *PM 2Ring*'s comment: if the list contains mutable things this approach does not work (and the function returns `None` [which then is consistent with the halting problem answer...]).

```
def tries_to_change(f, v):
    if isinstance(v, Sequence):
        # check if the sequence contains immutable elements only:
        try:
            set(v)
        except TypeError:
            # no idea what could happen to the elements in the list...
            return None

        v_immutable = tuple(v)
        try:
            f(v_immutable)
            return False
        except AttributeError:
            return True
```

Comment: Tuples aren't immutable in that sense: http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/10/python-tuples-immutable-but-potentially-changing.html

Comment: @jbasko yes, i know. as i said: it is crude. and i do not really know what the OP needs (this might be enough depending on what is inside a tuple). but you are right; should add that to the answer...

Comment: You could use a set to perform your test, since the `set` constructor will reject collections that contain unhashable items at any depth: `a=[1,2,3];t=(a,a);t[0].append(4);t;q=set();q.add(t)`

Comment: @PM2Ring: nice improvement! but then i'd only know if there is something that could be changed; not if it really will be changed.

Comment: Good point. :) But at least you know that if `v` _can_ be added to a set then it can't possibly mutated, so there's no need to perform further testing if that fails. Note that doing `set(v)` is not the same as doing `q=set();q.add(v)` since the latter (attempts to) add `v` as a single element, whereas the former (attempts to) iterate over `v` and construct a set with the items of `v` as its elements.

Comment: @PM2Ring: oh, i seem to have misunderstood. if `v` is a `list` then i check if all the items in `v` are immutable (with `set(v)`), right? and then i run the function with the `list` converted into a `tuple` and see if it fails or not. you would use `set` differently?

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* that it will either *always* change `v` or *never* change `v`, then you could do something like this:

```
class Checker(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.changed = False

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        super().__setitem__(index, value)
        self.changed = True

    # implementing the rest of the mutating methods, e.g. `update`
    # is left as an exercise for the reader

def m(f, v):
   '''return True if f modifies v. Otherwise, return False'''
   c = Checker()
   c.update(v)
   f(c)
   return c.changed
```

You *might* be able to use some code-path execution checking to see if all paths were executed, and/or do some weird AST hacking to remove any kind of conditionals... but you'd also have to make sure there wasn't any kind of stupid shenanigans like this:

```
def f(v):
    '''Do terrible things in terrible ways.'''

    q = v
    if q.update({1:1}):
        pass  # because it will never hit here, but it *will* modify `v`
    qux = [1,2]
    qux.append({'derp': v})
    qux[2]['derp'][42] = '...herring. A red one!'
```